# Is this a good way to do a game loop for an iPhone game?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, quartz-2d

I'm new to iPhone dev, but trying to build a 2D game. I was following a book, but the game loop it created basically said:

```
function gameLoop
    update()
    render()
    sleep(1/30th second)
    gameLoop
```

The reasoning was that this would run at 30fps. However, this seemed a little mental, because if my frame took 1/30th second, then it would run at 15fps (since it'll spend as much time sleeping as updating).

So, I did some digging and found the CADisplayLink class which would sync calls to my gameLoop function to the refresh rate (or a fraction of it). I can't find many samples of it, so I'm posting here for a code review :-) It seems to work as expected, and it includes passing the elapsed (frame) time into the Update method so my logic can be framerate-independant (however I can't actually find in the docs what CADisplayLink would do if my frame took more than its allowed time to run - I'm hoping it just does its best to catch up, and doesn't crash!).

```
//
//  GameAppDelegate.m
//
//  Created by Danny Tuppeny on 10/03/2010.
//  Copyright Danny Tuppeny 2010. All rights reserved.
//

#import "GameAppDelegate.h"
#import "GameViewController.h"
#import "GameStates/gsSplash.h"

@implementation GameAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
 // Create an instance of the first GameState (Splash Screen)
 [self doStateChange:[gsSplash class]];

 // Set up the game loop
 displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(gameLoop)];
 [displayLink setFrameInterval:2];
 [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void) gameLoop
{
 // Calculate how long has passed since the previous frame
 CFTimeInterval currentFrameTime = [displayLink timestamp];
 CFTimeInterval elapsed = 0;

 // For the first frame, we want to pass 0 (since we haven't elapsed any time), so only
 // calculate this in the case where we're not the first frame
 if (lastFrameTime != 0)
 {
  elapsed = currentFrameTime - lastFrameTime;
 }

 // Keep track of this frames time (so we can calculate this next time)
 lastFrameTime = currentFrameTime;

 NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", elapsed]);

 // Call update, passing the elapsed time in
 [((GameState*)viewController.view) Update:elapsed];
}

- (void) doStateChange:(Class)state
{
 // Remove the previous GameState
 if (viewController.view != nil)
 {
  [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
  [viewController.view release];
 }

 // Create the new GameState
 viewController.view = [[state alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, IPHONE_WIDTH, IPHONE_HEIGHT) andManager:self];

 // Now set as visible
 [window addSubview:viewController.view];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
 [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Any feedback would be appreciated :-)

PS. Bonus points if you can tell me why all the books use "viewController.view" but for everything else seem to use "[object name]" format. Why not [viewController view]?

Comment: Although this code works, it seems to stutter a little. The framerate isn't low, it just doesn't seem smooth. I think this may be because I'm syncing to the framerate and then *updating* in my game loop. The rendering is done in drawRect.

I think my code should be drawing directly in the method called (and maybe update should be done after the draw), but I can't find any good examples of CADisplayLink.

Comment: I changed the movement of my sprites to 30 pixels per second, and it seems completely smooth (with the very occasional frame dropped), so I think it was just down to the speed I'd set - eg. moving slightly more than a pixel per frame, which meant eventually it would jump two pixels in one frame, making it look uneven. I guess this is unavoidable.

Answer (score 2):

You have Cocos2D listed as a tag in your question but you're not actually using any Cocos2D code.  Have you considered doing a Cocos2D implementation for your games?  It will save you some unneeded hassle.

As for your syntax question `[myObject view]` is used for calling methods on `myObject` while `myObject.view` is used for setting/getting instance variables exposed as properties.  I don't recall if you can retrieve instance variables using `[myObject view]` as well but if that works then I guess the only difference between the two is the syntax and you could use both methods to retrieve instance variables.

Hope some of that rambling is useful to you.

Comment: Whoops! Told you I didn't know what I was doing! Removed the tag now.

Did some reading on the syntax thing, understand it better now. Seems that [myclass property] and myclass.property can do different things. The first is a property (which can execute code, though in most cases I suspect it just returns the variable) whereas the dot is accessing the variable directly (and won't have custom code).

Seems like the difference between exposing a private field and a property in C#, only that here they can both appear to have the same name!

Comment: Actually, now I'm confused, because I'm getting errors:

accessing unknown 'rect' getter method

Which makes me think that using dot is exactly the same as using get/set methods!

Comment: If you use the dot you need to define the instance variable you want to retrieve as a property and then synthesize it as well. Lookup syntax for "@property" and "@synthesize" calls.

Getter/setter methods get implicitly created for you but only after making use of @synthesize.  This is why you are getting an unknown 'rect' getter method.

Comment: I've done that now, though my understanding was that it just creates the get/set methods, so now:

object.myval = something

is just the same as doing:

[object setMyval:something];

?

Comment: From what I know yes object.myval = something and [object setMyval:something] should be equivalent.  Get/set methods for properties don't get created automatically for you to my knowledge until you synthesize them.

Answer (score -2):

From many GL example by Apple, I think you should use a timer.

```
animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/60.0)
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(updateAndRender)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:TRUE];
```

Comment: I believe CADisplayLink was added as a better way, but because it was only recently added, there seems to be little documentation/samples :(